# Why doesn't 'find' show this file?

Tags: shell, find, wildcards, quoting

Using `find` with `grep`, one can locate files that match a pattern:

```
# find | grep error
./solr-modifiedSolr4/SolrPhpClient/phpdocs/errors.html
./error_log
./includes/classes/error_log
```

However, using `find` alone the first file is not found:

```
# find . -name error*
./error_log
./includes/classes/error_log
```

Why doesn't `find` locate the `errors.html` file when not used with `grep`? How is `find` used to show this file as well?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to quote your argument `error*` because the shell expands it. So what you're actually running now is `find -name error_log`, because that's what the shell can expand it to (there's a file named `error_log` in your current directory).

```
find . -name 'error*'
```

Is the correct invocation for your use case.

Comment: an altenative writing is `find -name error\*` - one key less to press ;) this has the same effect, the `*` gets passed as an literate asterisk to the find command and is not expanded by your shell

Comment: When having trouble with the shell (how it interprets your command-line and passes all arguments and parameters to the actual command), re-run the command prepending it with the `echo` command. So, if you'd run `echo find . -name error*` it would have outputted `find . -name error_log`