# Understanding find wildcards

Tags: find, wildcards

Noob linux here trying to understand wildcard matching when using `find`.

```
#find /opt/spark/jars -name data*
#find /opt/spark/jars -name datan*
/opt/spark/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar
/opt/spark/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar
/opt/spark/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar
```

How come `data*` doesn't match anything but `datan*` *does*?

Comment: Do you have a file in your current directory named data... that doesn't start with datan?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55430/315749

Comment: Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596606/expansion-doubt/596608#596608

Comment: **Always** quote your patterns, e.g. `find /opt/spark/jars -name 'data*'` for the reason that @JeffSchaller hints at.

Comment: Thanks. `find /opt/spark/jars -name 'data*'` did work. After a cursory glance at those shared articles I don't fully understand why so I'm going to go back and re-read them now. Thanks.

Comment: "Do you have a file in your current directory named data... that doesn't start with datan?" yes, i did. I understand now :) thanks @JeffSchaller